# .NET Core MVC cloned project's local DB will not update with recent pull request

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I've been developing a .NET Core MVC project on my main computer. I upload to GitHub as I develop. One day I wanted to do some work on my laptop, so I cloned the project into Visual Studio. I ended up not working on the project though.

Since then, I have made some code-first migrations on my main computer. Everything is working fine. I wanted to work on my laptop again, so I pulled my changes. When I try to run my app, I get an error that one of my entities doesn't have a column that I added since I first cloned the project. The model class has the property for that column, and my migrations folder has the migration in it that should add the column, but the local DB entity on my laptop doesn't have the column. I'm not sure what's wrong, so any advice is appreciated.

Comment: if I understand everything right, you have forgotten to run DB migration on your laptop to apply new migration...

Comment: I think you understand it. So... if I do code first migration on my main computer, push to GitHub, then pull from GitHub on my laptop, I have to run the migrations again on my laptop?

Comment: yes, if you use local DB, cause in this case you have 2 independent version of DBs (on each computer) and migrations apply per database. By default, EF Core keeps track of which migrations have been applied to the database by recording them in a table named `__EFMigrationsHistory`, you can check it.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turned out that DB migrations were needed to be run on the laptop to have the same table schema.

Cause local databases are used for development, there are 2 independent versions of them (per computer) and so cause DB migration runs per database (the last version of applied migration could be checked in `__EFMigrationsHistory` table if EF Core is used) it is needed to explicitly apply changes to sync version of databases.